# How do I integrate $4(1-x)^3 I_{(0,1)}(x)$

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm not familiar with the $I_{(0,1)}$ part of the equation. What does this notation mean and I do I integrate it?

Comment: $I_{(0,1)}$ is the function with value $1$ on $(0,1)$ and zero otherwise. So, drop it from the integrand and integrate from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$I_{(0,1)}(x)=1$ if $x\in (0,1)$ and $I_{(0,1)}(x)=0$ otherwise.

So your integral becames

$$\int_{0}^{1}4(1-x)^3dx$$

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an indicator function; a piecewise function that has value $1$ when the argument $x$ is in the interval $(0;1)$ and value $0$ elsewhere.

$$I_{(0;1)}(x)=\begin{cases}1 &:& x\in(0;1)\\0 &:& x\notin(0;1)\end{cases}$$

---

$$\int_\Bbb R 4\,(1-x)^3\,I_{(0;1)}(x)\,\mathrm d x~=~\int_0^1 4\,(1-x)^3\,\mathrm d x$$